# sql command does not execute properly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a two tables in my database `instructors` and `courses` . I want to join them and for this reason wrote this code

```
$this->db->join('instructors', 'instructors.id = courses.instructor_id', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get_where('courses', array('courses_slug' => $slug));
return $query->row_array();
```

This code means:

```
SELECT * FROM `courses` LEFT JOIN `instructors` ON `instructors`.`id` = `courses`.`instructor_id` WHERE `courses_slug` = 'abituriyent-hazirligi'
```

But when I write this code to check:

```
$data['courses'] = $this->popular_courses_model->get_popular_courses($slug);
echo $data['courses']['id'];
die();
```

It writes the instructors id, not id of the course. Where can be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: Codeigniter3 framework

Comment: `$data['courses'] = ...` looks weird... If the function returns rows then your `echo` makes no sense to me. Try dumping the return value of the function and looking at it in entirety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using joins you should explicitly call out what columns you want returned like:

```
$select = "c.id, c.name, c.instructor_id, i.name instructor_name";

return $this->db->select($select)
//equivalent to "instructors as i" 
->join('instructors i', 'i.id = c.instructor_id', 'left')
->where('c.courses_slug', $slug)
//equivalent to "courses as c" 
->get('courses c')->row_array();
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: no problem! As you go forward, this practice in general will speed up your quires because the more joins you add the slower it gets in the long run and the more thinking you do for the query the faster it process everything

Answer (score 1):

You are joining two table with columns of the same name ('id').  You need to be specific in your select for the columns and rename ('AS') if necessary.

```
select courses.id as course_id, instructor.id as instructor_id, ...
```

Comment: But I need to select everything for courses page. Should I write all columns?

Comment: I'm skeptical. Doesn't the ORM handle that? I'm already seeing the table prefixes used in the query. Suppose depends if *that* "code means", what OP think it means...

Comment: You can shorthand it with courses.*, but you need to handle the duplicates the way you need them.

Comment: OK. Suppose I misused "ORM" there too. This is just building out SQL and returning an array isn't it...